HuggingFace: Efficient Large-Scale Embedding Extraction for DNA Sequences Using Transformers
I have a very large dataframe (60+ million rows) that I would like to use a transformer model to grab the embeddings for these rows (DNA sequences). Basically, this involves tokenizing first, then I can get the embeddings.
Because of RAM limits, I have found that tokenizing and then embedding all in one py file won't work. Here's the workaround I found that worked for a dataframe with ~30million rows (but it isn't working for the larger df):

tokenizing-- saving the output as 200 chunks/shards
feeding those 200 chunks separately to get embedded
these embeddings then get concatenated into one larger file of embeddings

final embedding file should have these columns:
[['Chromosome', 'label', 'embeddings']]
Overall, I'm a little lost in terms of how I can get this to work for my larger dataset.
I've looked into streaming the dataset, but I don't think that will actually help because I need all of the embeddings, not just a few. Perhaps it could work if I stream the tokenization and feed it into the embedding process a bit at a time (delete the tokens along the way). This way, I don't have to save the tokens. Please correct me if this is not feasible.
Ideally, I would like to avoid having to shard the data, but I would just like the code to run at this point without reaching the RAM limit.
step 1
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(element_final[['Chromosome', 'sequence', 'label']]) 

dataset = dataset.shuffle(seed=42)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(f"InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref")
def tokenize_function(examples):
    outputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(examples["sequence"], return_tensors="pt", truncation=False, padding=False, max_length=80)
    return outputs
    
# Creating tokenized  dataset
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True, batch_size=2000)

tokenized_dataset.save_to_disk(f"tokenized_elements/tokenized_{ELEMENT}", num_shards=200)

step 2 (this code runs over each of the 200 shards)
input_file = f"tokenized_elements/tokenized_{ELEMENT_LABEL}/{filename}.arrow"

# Load input data
d1 = Dataset.from_file(input_file)

def embed_function(examples):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()

    inputs = torch.tensor(examples['input_ids'])  # Convert to tensor
    inputs = inputs.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids=inputs, output_hidden_states=True)

    # Step 3: Extract the embeddings
    hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states  # List of hidden states from all layers
    embeddings = hidden_states[-1]  # Assuming you want embeddings from the last layer
    averaged_embeddings = torch.mean(embeddings, dim=1)  # Calculate mean along dimension 1 (the dimension with size 86)
    averaged_embeddings = averaged_embeddings.to(torch.float32)  # Ensure float32 data type
    return {'embeddings': averaged_embeddings}

# Map embeddings function to input data
embeddings = d1.map(embed_function, batched=True, batch_size=1550)
embeddings = embeddings.remove_columns(["input_ids", "attention_mask"])

# Save embeddings to disk
output_dir = f"embedded_elements/embeddings_{ELEMENT_LABEL}/{filename}"  # Assuming ELEMENT_LABEL is defined elsewhere

step 3: concatenate all 200 shards of embeddings into 1.

Where does the program get stuck for your larger df? I don't see why you think streaming is a bad option. I think that reducing your original df size by streaming in subsets of your data at a time is a logical starting point.

How should I adjust my code to incorporate streaming?

That would depend on your data. Can you please produce a minimal reproduceable example?

My newest post goes over this in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78863444/efficiently-fetch-sequences-for-sliding-window-large-dataset
