Efficiently fetch sequences for sliding window (large dataset)
The dataset I have stored are just coordinates of DNA sequence.
df:
chr   start    stop   label  
chr1   9000    9100    1  
chr1   8803    8903     1  
chr1   8903    9000     0  

My goal is to expand the original dataset by creating a sliding window around each coordinate to capture context sequences.
new_df:
chr    start         stop        label  
chr1   9000-5000    9000+5000      1  
chr1   9001-5000    9001+5000      1  
chr1   9002-5000    9002+5000      1  
...
chr1   9100-5000    9100+5000      1  
...


Create Sliding Window: For each entry in my original dataset, generate new rows by creating a sliding window of 5000 nucleotides on either side of the start and stop coordinates. This effectively captures the sequence context around each original coordinate.
Expand Dataset: For each original entry, create new rows where each row represents a specific position within the 5000-nucleotide context window. For example, if the original start is 9000, I will generate rows with start values from 9000-5000 to 9000+5000, and similarly adjust the stop values. Each sequence is now 10,001 characters in length now.

using this function:
def expand_coordinates(element_locs, context=3):
    # Vectorized expansion of coordinates
    start = element_locs['Start'].astype(int)
    end = element_locs['End'].astype(int)
    
    expanded_data = []
    for idx, row in element_locs.iterrows():
        chr_name = row['Chromosome']
        chr_start = start[idx]
        chr_end = end[idx]
        
        for i in range(chr_start, chr_end + 1):
            expanded_data.append({
                'Chromosome': chr_name,
                'Start': max((i - 1) - context, 0),
                'End': min(i + context, max_sizes[chr_name])
            })
    
    expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_data)
    return expanded_df


Fetch Sequences: Use the expanded coordinates from new_df to fetch the corresponding DNA sequences from the dataset.

def get_element_seqs(element_locs, context=3):
    expanded_df = expand_coordinates(element_locs, context=context)
    # Optimize genome fetching
    genome = pysam.Fastafile(ref_genome)
    def fetch_sequences(row):
        return genome.fetch(row['Chromosome'], row['Start'], row['End'])
    # Fetch sequences in a vectorized way
    expanded_df['sequence'] = expanded_df.apply(fetch_sequences, axis=1)
    return element_seqs


Tokenize the sequences

dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(element_final[['Chromosome', 'sequence', 'label']]) 

dataset = dataset.shuffle(seed=42)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(f"InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref")
def tokenize_function(examples):
    outputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(examples["sequence"], return_tensors="pt", truncation=False, padding=False, max_length=80)
    return outputs
    
# Creating tokenized  dataset
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True, batch_size=2000)



Get the embeddings from the tokens

input_file = f"tokenized_elements/tokenized_{ELEMENT_LABEL}/{filename}.arrow"

# Load input data
d1 = Dataset.from_file(input_file)

def embed_function(examples):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()

    inputs = torch.tensor(examples['input_ids'])  # Convert to tensor
    inputs = inputs.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids=inputs, output_hidden_states=True)

    # Step 3: Extract the embeddings
    hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states  # List of hidden states from all layers
    embeddings = hidden_states[-1]  # Assuming you want embeddings from the last layer
    averaged_embeddings = torch.mean(embeddings, dim=1)  # Calculate mean along dimension 1 (the dimension with size 86)
    averaged_embeddings = averaged_embeddings.to(torch.float32)  # Ensure float32 data type
    return {'embeddings': averaged_embeddings}

# Map embeddings function to input data
embeddings = d1.map(embed_function, batched=True, batch_size=1550)
embeddings = embeddings.remove_columns(["input_ids", "attention_mask"])

# Save embeddings to disk
output_dir = f"embedded_elements/embeddings_{ELEMENT_LABEL}/{filename}"  # Assuming ELEMENT_LABEL is defined elsewhere


Plug in the embeddings to XGBoost

This ends up giving me huge datasets that makes my code crash (e.g. I start with 700K rows and they get expanded to 1000million rows). I have been using pandas, so maybe that's the problem too? Another issue is I'm not using batching I think?
Unfortunately, my code keeps crashing between steps 2+3. I think I need to implement batching, but I'm unsure how everything will work since I eventually will need to feed in output to an LLM.

Rewriting the expand_coordinates function since your process fails between steps 2 and 3. In step 3, expanded_df['sequence'] = expanded_df.apply(fetch_sequences, axis=1) should be replaced with something like expanded_df.merge(fetch_sequences: pd.DataFrame, ...) since merge is vectorized. It is a misconception that putting ANY function inside an apply is a vectorized approach!
def expand_coordinates(element_locs: pd.DataFrame, context: int = 3):
    # create a column of ranges (memory efficient since ranges are lazy)
    element_locs['range'] = element_locs.apply(lambda row: range(row['start'], row['stop'] + 1), axis=1)
    # explode is a vectorized operation
    element_locs = element_locs.explode('range')
    
    element_locs['start'] = np.maximum(element_locs['start']-context, 0)
    element_locs['stop'] = np.minimum(element_locs['stop']+context, 5000)  # <-- 5000 is an arbitrary maximum for demo

    return element_locs

I performed a few load tests and this fared well (although nowhere near the scale you're dealing with since I'm testing this on my laptop - Ubuntu 16GB). Results below. Please note - There is a significant amount of variability in testing since I'm generating the data through random generators. The critical piece here is the explosion factor (target rows/initial rows) which depends solely on start and stop values (randomnly generated in my case).
Initial rows: 100
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 511,628
Explosion time: 0.1 sec


Initial rows: 1,000
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 4,965,974
Explosion time: 0.77 sec


Initial rows: 10,000
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 50,074,976
Explosion time: 7.32 sec


Initial rows: 11,000
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 54,922,952
Explosion time: 8.1 sec


Initial rows: 12,000
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 59,966,220
Explosion time: 8.98 sec


Initial rows: 15,000
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 75,115,987
Explosion time: 11.51 sec


Initial rows: 20,000
Generation time: 0.0 sec
Target rows: 100,010,662

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9:SIGKILL)

At the scale you're dealing with, PANDAS is definitely a bad idea. Look into spark if you have access to the relevant infra.
